# Python print() corrupting memory allocated by ctypes

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm working on some code to act as a Python wrapper for a rather large C++ project. I have created a class wrapper with the associated function wrappers which make direct calls to the DLL. Since it is a C++ project, it needs a C wrapper as well, which is implemented and working correctly.

```
const char* MyClass::GetName() {
  printf("Name at %p\n", &Name);
  printf("Name is %s\n", Name);
  return Name;
}
```

My Python class `d` is constructed using the `Open()` method. There is a C++ function `GetName()` which simply returns the value of `Name`. I modified this function in the C++ source to print out the address and value of the `Name` variable for debugging. The `get_name()` function in Python is the wrapper.

```py
??.Open.restype = POINTER(c_int)
??.GetName.argtypes = (POINTER(c_int),)
??.GetName.restype = c_char_p
```

```py
d = MyClass()
d.get_name()
print('hi')
d.get_name()
```

This outputs the following:

```bash
Name at 0x80012e598
Name is device_name
hi
Name at 0x80012e598
Name is hi
```

Any other amount of code I have tested so far maintains "Name is device_name" but when it comes to print the value comes back empty or as the last thing passed to `print()` (it is empty when the last thing passed was large). It seems like the buffer used by `print()` overlaps with the allocated memory for the object in C++. If I run the script with the `-u` flag (unbuffered outputs), `Name` it is empty every single time:

```bash
Name at 0x800111368
Name is device_name
hi
Name at 0x800111368
Name is
```

Since the C++ is printing out the address of the variable, I know it hasn't changed, which means Python is modifying it when it shouldn't be allowed to.

What steps should I take to further debug/resolve this? Thank you in advance.

---

## EDIT

I worked on a minimal reproducible example and discovered the cause of the issue, but do not understand why. It was a part of the **init** for my Python class. The argument is a string `Name` which needs to be converted to `bytes()` to be passed through ctypes. I will show one working example and one breaking example. What is the difference between the two, causing one to work and the other not?

```py
# Create working class
class MyWorkingClass():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.obj = lib.MyClass_Open(name)

    def get_name(self):
        return lib.MyClass_GetName(self.obj).decode('utf-8')

# This part works
name = bytes('my_name', 'utf-8')
working = MyWorkingClass(name)

for i in range(5):
    print(working.get_name())
```

And this one gets the wrong data back:

```py
# Create breaking class
class MyBreakingClass():

    def __init__(self, name):
        name = bytes(name, 'utf-8')
        self.obj = lib.MyClass_Open(name)

    def get_name(self):
        return lib.MyClass_GetName(self.obj).decode('utf-8')

# This part doesn't work
breaking = MyBreakingClass('my_name')
for i in range(5):
    print(breaking.get_name())
```

In both cases, the same exact `name` should be (from my understanding anyway) getting passed to `MyClass_Open()`, but clearly that is not the case. Why?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].  Show the *exact* C++ and Python code that reproduces the issue, not snippets.

Comment: Your `printf` statements may not be telling you quite what you think they are.  Apparently, `Name` is an instance variable of class `MyClass`.  You are printing its *address*, `&Name`, which will not change for any given instance of that class.  You do not know whether a new (pointer) value is being assigned to `Name`, *vs* whether the contents of the string to which it points are being changed.

Comment: If the example Python and C++ code are both representative, then it seems the problem must be in the `get_name()` wrapper.  That you have not managed to reproduce a similar issue by other means than `print()` is unlikely to be significant.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I will work on that now

Comment: @MarkTolonen I did what you asked for and found a solution to the issue, but still don't understand why. Could you take a look at my edit above?

Comment: A guess without seeing the C++ code: Only the pointer to `name` is stored in the C++ class, and the pointer in the breaking class points to the local variable `name` in `__init__` which goes out of scope after it returns.  So you have undefined behavior at that point.  In the working class, `name` is in the global namespace and isn't destructed during the `for` loop.

Comment: @MarkTolonen That makes sense, you are correct that it is a pointer but I guess I had assumed the Python and the C++ were not working out of the same memory. That changes a lot... thank you so much for your help and if you make a post as an answer I'd gladly accept it and upvote :p

Comment: @MarkTolonen but the pointer should be to the *object*, not the variable. But that still makes sense

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Potato Patato. To get technical `ctypes` uses `PyBytes_AsString` to obtain a pointer to the internal buffer of the `bytes` object, which is then passed to the C interface. If the C interface stores that pointer and returns and the `bytes` object's reference count goes to zero, the object is freed and that pointer becomes invalid. Since that pointer points to the internal buffer, the C code also must not modify the pointer contents as well because that violates the immutability of `bytes` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the C++ code (not shown) is storing a pointer to name being passed.  In the breaking case, the `bytes` object whose internal buffer that pointer references goes out of scope, freeing the buffer and creating undefined behavior.

In the OP's original problem, it is likely the allocation for `'hi'` ended up at the same address, but anything could happen due to UB.

Here's a minimal example:

**test.cpp** - implied implementation from description

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

class MyClass {
    const char* _name;
public:
    MyClass(const char* name) : _name(name) {}    // store pointer during construction
    const char* GetName() const { return _name; } // access pointer later
};

extern "C" {

API MyClass* MyClass_Open(const char* name) {
    return new MyClass(name); // leaks in this example
}

API const char* MyClass_GetName(MyClass* p) {
    return p->GetName();
}

}
```

**test.py** - combined examples and made complete

```py
import ctypes as ct

lib = ct.CDLL('./test')
lib.MyClass_Open.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,
lib.MyClass_Open.restype = ct.c_void_p
lib.MyClass_GetName.argtypes = ct.c_void_p,
lib.MyClass_GetName.restype = ct.c_char_p

# Create working class
class MyWorkingClass():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.obj = lib.MyClass_Open(name)

    def get_name(self):
        return lib.MyClass_GetName(self.obj)

# This part works
# bytes object is created here
# "name" is the only reference but it is still in scope during get_name() below
name = bytes('my_name', 'utf-8')
working = MyWorkingClass(name)

for i in range(5):
    print(working.get_name())

# Create breaking class
class MyBreakingClass():

    def __init__(self, name):
        # bytes object is created here
        # "name" is the only reference and goes out of scope when __init__ returns
        name = bytes(name, 'utf-8')
        self.obj = lib.MyClass_Open(name)

    def get_name(self):
        return lib.MyClass_GetName(self.obj)

# This part doesn't work
breaking = MyBreakingClass('my_name')
for i in range(5):
    print(breaking.get_name()) # garbage output
```

Output:

```
b'my_name'
b'my_name'
b'my_name'
b'my_name'
b'my_name'
b'\xf0'        # could be anything due to UB
b'\xf0'
b'\xf0'
b'\xf0'
b'\xf0'
```